# Lambda Expression to close my SocketConversation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a test application that spawns a number of SocketConversations with a server. In the old days, I would have added an interface called ClosedWhenDone or something that defined a close method and pass an instance in that would notify the calling class that the SocketConversation is complete.

I'm new to java 8 and want to teach myself lambda functions. I have looked at these: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html, http://viralpatel.net/blogs/lambda-expressions-java-tutorial/, http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-we-need-lambda-expressions, http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-we-need-lambda-expressions-0, and http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-we-need-lambda-expressions.

So, based on my research, I added a parameter to my constructor:

```
private Predicate<SocketConversation>       closePredicate;
private long                                delay;
private boolean                             done;
private int                                 index;

public SocketConversation(URI uri, int idx, String line, long delay, Predicate<SocketConversation> predicate) {
    index = idx;
    socket = new AirSocketClient(uri, this);
    closePredicate = predicate;
       ...
}
```

Then when my conversation is over, I do the following:

```
    socket.close();
    closePredicate.close(this);
```

The close here, though, generates an error:

```
The method close(SocketConversation) is undefined for the type Predicate<SocketConversation>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that Predicate has no close() method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html. I can't understand why you want to pass a Predicate to this method.

Comment: @JBNizet OIC. I understand more about Predicate now. I guess this is a situation where I'd use a closure in JavaScript so i didn't need to create an interace. I thought there'd be a way to do this using lambda functions and thought this was it. In this case, then, is there a way to do what I'm looking for if Predicate isn't it?

Comment: Define a CloseWhenDone interface, as you would have done before you knew about lambda expressions. If it has a single abstract method, the caller will be able to use a lamda expression to create the CloseWhenDone instance.

Comment: @JBNizet So this isn't a good application for lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a callback that lets the caller know that the conversation is complete, by calling a bit of code that the caller has specified. This sounds like a perfect use of lambdas. In the "old" days (prior to Java 8) you'd specify some interface and the caller would pass in an instance of an anonymous inner class. This can easily be done with a lambda instead.

You could define your own interface, but you don't need to in this case because most of the simple interfaces have already been defined. In this case the callback is passed an instance of a `SocketConversation` and returns nothing. The functional interface for this is a `Consumer`, which is already defined in `java.util.function` package. It's generic, so you want a `Consumer<SocketConversation>`. Your class would look something like this:

```
private Consumer<SocketConversation> callback;

public SocketConversation(URI uri, int idx, String line, long delay, Consumer<SocketConversation> callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    ...
}
```

and later on, when the conversation is closed, you'd do this:

```
    socket.close();
    callback.accept(this);
```

Callers could pass a lambda expression as the callback like this:

```
SocketConversation conv = new SocketConversation(uri, idx, line, delay,
    sc -> System.out.println("conversation " + sc + " is done"));
```